# Big ontology based on rules

Tags: prolog, rules, ontology

Could someone tell me where I can find an ontology based on rules, not an OWL one. It can be a Prolog one, or similar.

The ontology should have between 10.000 and 100.000 rules in size, or even more. The maximum limit is not very important, the important is the minimum.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe SO it's not the best place for this question

Answer (score 1):

Well, mostly depends on what you mean by 'rule'. It's a very generic term... If you just want a shallow data model, you can easily generate your own 'ontology' populating SWI-Prolog well engineered [Semantic Web](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%28%27packages/semweb.html%27%29) DB with some data of your own choice.

For instance, attempting to learn more about RDF, I've done a similar job, putting filesystem info (Prolog sources, actually) in an 'ontology' I designed, and then drawn various hierarchies, testing my pqGraphviz interface.

I think you can get millions 'rules' this way, in seconds... but, how to do something *useful* with such data it's much more difficult. A good step would be integrating in [Cliopatria](http://cliopatria.swi-prolog.org/home), but I didn't get it.

There are so many resource available... for instance ROS, and specifically [knowrob](http://www.knowrob.org/), seems a good place to search, since it has specific SWI-Prolog hooks.

I hope someone other will contribute a more comprehensive/interesting answer...

Comment: By rule I mean IF...THEN statements. Thank you.

Comment: expert system, a la MYCIN ?

Comment: It's for a new platform I'm developing. It can be defined as an expert system or a rule engine.

Comment: @CapelliC What didn't you get about ClioPatria?

Comment: @WouterBeek: has been some time ago... the pirates demo didn't worked so well